# my input np array turns into different shape when input in the keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The image has a shape of `(512, 2048, 3)` but I get a ValueError when running `preds_train = new_model.predict(img, batch_size=1)` :

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1, 2048, 3), dtype=float32)
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 2048, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * True
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * True
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 3:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 2048, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1')
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 4:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 2048, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

I've printed the initial dimensions of the shape so I'm sure it's `(512, 2048, 3)` and additionally when i trained the model i did so using images of that shape. I don't know why I can't test the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using model.evaluate(x_test)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reshape with one more dimension since your model is trained in that way, for example try this:

```
width,height,ch=img.shape
img_input=img.reshape((1,width,height,ch))
```